# Finding differences in two datasets, creating a 'check' variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets, one older than the other, and I would like to compare the differences between the two datasets, creating a new dataset that may include this information. Both the datasets have the same columns.
For instance, dataset 1:

```
Cust1              Neigh_Cust2  Age   Net_Value
Mickey Mouse       Minnie       30     50000
Mickey Mouse       Snoopy       30     24000
Mickey Mouse       Duffy Duck   30     21000
Minnie             Mickey Mouse 25     30000
Minnie             Batman       25     12000
```

dataset 2 (most updated):

```
Cust1              Neigh_Cust2  Age   Net_Value
Mickey Mouse       Batman       30     23000
Mickey Mouse       Superman     30     24000
Mickey Mouse       Duffy Duck   30     21000
Minnie             Mickey Mouse 25     30000
Minnie             Batman       25     12000
Batman             Mickey Mouse 48     53000
```

The length of the two datasets might be different.
My expected output would be

```
Cust1              Neigh_Cust2  Age   Net_Value  New/Missing?
Mickey Mouse       Batman       30     23000        New
Mickey Mouse       Superman     30     24000        New
Batman             Mickey Mouse 48     53000        New
Mickey Mouse       Minnie       30     50000        Missing
Mickey Mouse       Snoopy       30     24000        Missing
```

I have thought of using isin but I have two fields (`Cust1` and `Neigh_Cust2`) that I am interested in to see which observations are included or not in the other dataset so maybe this is not the best way to look at the problem and get the expected output.

Comment: why are different rows in third df?

Comment: Hi jezrael, the third dataframe is resulting from the differences in the two datasets. There are some rows included in df1 that are not in df2 and vice versa. The new variable New/Missing should give information on rows included in one dataset but not in the other one.

Comment: hmmm, I m not answerer. Best ask him.

Comment: Is necessary compare all columns? Not only `(Cust1 and Neigh_Cust2)` ?

Comment: no, it would be sufficient compare only Cust1 and Neigh_Cust2. I would expect different values in the other columns so I would get more differences than necessary in case of comparing all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compare by some columns use:

```
a = df1.set_index(['Cust1','Neigh_Cust2']).index
b = df2.set_index(['Cust1','Neigh_Cust2']).index

df = pd.concat([df2[~b.isin(a)].assign(NewOrMissing = 'New'),
                df1[~a.isin(b)].assign(NewOrMissing = 'Missing')])
print (df)
          Cust1   Neigh_Cust2  Age  Net_Value NewOrMissing
0  Mickey Mouse        Batman   30      23000          New
1  Mickey Mouse      Superman   30      24000          New
5        Batman  Mickey Mouse   48      53000          New
0  Mickey Mouse        Minnie   30      50000      Missing
1  Mickey Mouse        Snoopy   30      24000      Missing
```

If no duplicates per `Cust1, Neigh_Cust2` in original DataFrames, so duplicates are created only by join:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1.assign(NewOrMissing = 'Missing'), 
                df2.assign(NewOrMissing = 'New')])
        .drop_duplicates(['Cust1','Neigh_Cust2'], keep=False))
print (df)
          Cust1   Neigh_Cust2  Age  Net_Value NewOrMissing
0  Mickey Mouse        Minnie   30      50000      Missing
1  Mickey Mouse        Snoopy   30      24000      Missing
0  Mickey Mouse        Batman   30      23000          New
1  Mickey Mouse      Superman   30      24000          New
5        Batman  Mickey Mouse   48      53000          New
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and help, jezrael.

Comment: @V_sqrt -Hmm,accepted answer compare all columns, maybe ask for change answer.

Comment: I think both answers are valid. mozway's answer also provided indication (in the NB) on how to compare specified columns using 'on' (in my case, `on=['Cust1', 'Neigh_Cust2']`).

Comment: @V_sqrt - hmm, do you try it? Output is different.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with `indicator=True`:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on=list(df1.columns), indicator=True, how='outer')
    .query('_merge != "both"')
    .replace({'_merge': {'left_only': 'Missing', 'right_only': 'New'}})
    .rename(columns={'_merge': 'New/Missing?'})
)
```

*NB. I am comparing here on all columns, but you can change this using the `on` parameter*

output:

```
          Cust1   Neigh_Cust2  Age  Net_Value New/Missing?
0  Mickey Mouse        Minnie   30      50000      Missing
1  Mickey Mouse        Snoopy   30      24000      Missing
5  Mickey Mouse        Batman   30      23000          New
6  Mickey Mouse      Superman   30      24000          New
7        Batman  Mickey Mouse   48      53000          New
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, mozway. Your answer is very clear.